# Xcode crashes when dragging from Interface Builder after deleting Bridging Header

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder, xib

I tried using some Objective-C code in a Swift project but ended up deleting said code and the bridging-header when I found an alternate way to achieve result. Everything seems to work fine (i.e. running build, existing outlets in IB connecting etc) apart from when I try to create new outlet connections by dragging from IB using Assistant Editor to .swift files. I figure this has something to do with deleting my bridging header but I'm not sure what. I've tried running Clean and also restarting computer, no luck.

EDIT: Should mention the problem isn't inability to drag, it's that Xcode crashes after typing name for outlet and hitting enter.

EDIT 2: Here's the error output from Xcode upon crashing:

```
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D2105
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): +[IDESwiftSourceCodeGenerator     isTeardownCounterpart:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x112de75c0
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff94e37024 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00000001011d9bb4 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff9212776e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff94e39fad +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff94d7fe24 ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x00007fff94d7f998 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  6  0x0000000112d30532 __91-[IDESwiftSourceCodeGenerator prepareToAddPropertyWithName:type:inClassItem:options:error:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDELanguageSupportUI)
  7  0x000000010266ceb4 -[IDESourceCodeGenerator prepareToAddSourceCodeForCounterparts:documentLocationForCounterpartBlock:addSourceCodeForCounterpartBlock:options:error:] (in IDEKit)
  8  0x0000000112d3013f -[IDESwiftSourceCodeGenerator prepareToAddPropertyWithName:type:inClassItem:options:error:] (in IDELanguageSupportUI)
  9  0x0000000112d0b69b -[IDEIBSwiftOutletSourceCodeConnectionContext prepareToInsertSourceCode:] (in IDELanguageSupportUI)
 10  0x000000010c3f0a86 -[IBSourceCodeConnectionEndPointHandler insertOrPrepareToInsertSourceCodeForConnectionContext:prepareOrInsertBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 11  0x000000010c3f0eda -[IBSourceCodeConnectionEndPointHandler insertCodeForConnectionContext:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 12  0x000000010c3f1bbd -[IBSourceCodeConnectionEndPointHandler configuredAndCompletedConnectionWithSourceObject:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 13  0x000000010c184b1b -[IBConnectionManager beginOldSchoolConnectingFromObject:withEvent:inWindow:usingSourceLocator:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14  0x000000010c184e74 -[IBConnectionManager beginOldSchoolConnectingFromEditorCanvasFrameController:initialEndPoint:withEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 15  0x000000010c270bf5 -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController sendEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 16  0x000000010c497689 -[IBViewEditorCanvasFrameController sendEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 17  0x000000010c25fe85 -[IBEditorCanvasFrame mouseDragged:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 18  0x00007fff8f0cbf12 -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
 19  0x00007fff8ea5dd76 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 20  0x00000001024a7168 -[IDEWorkspaceWindow sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 21  0x00007fff8ea5a312 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 22  0x0000000102250c14 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 23  0x00007fff8e983c68 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 24  0x00007fff8e900354 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 25  0x00007fff939b25c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInvalidArgumentException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your project is corrupted. You could try to drag  and drop your outlet from your code to your xib file.

Type this in the .swift file:

@IBOutlet var varname: Type!

And now drag from your code to your xib file.

Comment: That works great, thanks very much :) Trying to figure out how the project got corrupted, wish I hadn't bothered with that bridging header now :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your class and module are correct?

[image]

Can you tap the arrow and your ViewController implementation is displayed?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to mention, that was one of the first things I checked and the correct implementation is displayed. Also forgot to mention that the problem is when I drag from xib to .swift using Assistant Editor, the error comes when I type in a name for the outlet, hit enter, then Xcode crashes.